# Acra not working properly in onCreate() of the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, acra

For testing purposes i create an error in my onCreate() method of my MainActivity.
Acra recognises that and displays a Toast.

```
02-23 19:05:35.075: E/ACRA(599): ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for .... Building report.
02-23 19:05:35.080: I/ACRA(599): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
02-23 19:05:35.080: D/ACRA(599): Writing crash report file 1361642735000.stacktrace.
02-23 19:05:35.125: D/ACRA(599): Waiting for Toast + worker...
02-23 19:05:35.125: D/dalvikvm(599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 278K, 18% free 2512K/3032K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 29ms
02-23 19:05:38.160: D/ACRA(599): About to create DIALOG from #handleException
02-23 19:05:38.160: D/ACRA(599): Creating Dialog for 1361642735000.stacktrace
02-23 19:05:38.170: D/ACRA(599): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
02-23 19:05:38.190: E/ACRA(599): ... fatal error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.../....MainActivity}: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
```

But after that everything happens again and again endlessly...
The Toast appears again, I see the stackstrce again...

When I create an error in, lets say onOptionsItemSelected(), everything works as expected. The Toast appears. My app closes. Dialog appears. Thats what I want...

But why does this not work in onCreate() properly?

Acra library (version 4.4.0) is in libs folder.

MainActivity:

```
import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.annotation.*;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;

import android.app.Application;

@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "",
        mailTo = "my_email_address", 
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text,
        resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
        resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info,
        resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title,
        resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt,
        resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast
        )

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="MyApplication" >

        <activity android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" />
```

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int i = 1/0; // raise an error for acra

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);
}
```

The Runnable:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // doing stuff here...

        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Post the MainActivity's onCreate(), it *seems* like your Activity is being restarted.

Comment: I thought my App would not start the Runnable when an error happened before? How can I prevent that?

Comment: @Oliver: Are you able to bring up the dialog successfully. In my case, ACRA fails to bring up the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this behavior seems to be an Acra bug that will get fixed in version 4.5 -> https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/42

Comment: Are you able to bring up the dialog successfully. In my case, ACRA fails to bring up the dialog. I am using 4.5 ACRA.